# send email notifications on push from a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

Sorry if this has already been answered before (if so please reference any links). I am looking for a way to send out email notifications on git pushes to a GitHub repo.

I realize that there is a email service hook available. But I'd like to send to 3 addresses and setting up a googlegroup for that seems to be overkill. I have read about post-receive hooks but I am not sure how to set that up on GitHub. Would like to know if there are ways to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the email service hook, no email-on-push notifications are currently available on Github. You can thus not canonically send such notifications to more than to email addresses at once.

You can, however, work around that by setting up a mailing list or email forward that distributes the email to all interested parties.